# Disable action bar home button depending on screen orientation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to disable the home button in the horizontal screen orientation - not only disable the action behind the button but make the button look like it's not clickable.

Would that be possible on Android?

It is for an `Activity` (not a `Fragment`), I currently don't use `setRetainInstance()` but I probably will.

I am using ActionBarSherlock but I plan to use appcompat somewhere in the future.

Comment: @SpringBreaker: you are misunderstanding the question. it is matter of  of actionbar,not device's home button.

Comment: You need to give more context here, is it for an activity or a fragment or else? Do you use setRetainInstance? Maybe the code of what you tried will help.

Comment: It is for an activity, I currently don't use `setRetainInstance()` but I probably will.

Comment: @REACHUS: are you using `actionbarsherlock` or `appcompat` library to support lower versions or just using default `actionbar` for higher version? plz add more details in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it by adding following lines in `onResume` method of your activity ,

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
    {
    // code to do for Portrait Mode
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    } else {
    // code to do for Landscape Mode         
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

**Note:** use `getSupportActionBar()` while using `actionbarsherlock` or `appcompat` library. and use `getActionBar()` when you don't support lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test the following code but it should give you an idea of what I would do:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: Well, Mehul got the same idea!

Comment: Yeah! I was writing answer to handle both orientation.so that he can understand it well.